# How can I compare computational complexities : O(k * M(n)) and O(log^6(n))?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Suppose that I have two computational complexities :

1. `O(k * M(n))` - computational complexity of [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), where `k` is number of exponent bits , `n` is number of digits , and `M(n)` is computational complexity of the [Newton's division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).
2. `O(log^6(n))` - computational complexity of an algorithm.

How can I determine which one of these two complexities is less "expensive" ? In fact notation `M(n)` is that what confusing me most .

Comment: Isn't that, according to how Wikipedia defines modular exponentation, it's complexity is simply `O(n)` -- to calculate a^n(mod c) we have to do `n` mults + 1 division? Additionally, your `O(k * M(n))` seems to be concerned with bit complexity, whereas 2nd complexity is not bit complexity.

Comment: @VictorSorokin,[complexity of arithmetic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions)

Comment: Okay, so `M(n)` is `time to multiply 2 n-bit numbers`, as defined in linked arXiv article (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2091v2). Is `O(n)` good enough estimation for this?

Comment: @VictorSorokin,I don't know...

Comment: Are you interested in the theoretical complexity or the actual usability? Big-O notation only describes the asymptotic behavior, i.e. as `n` goes to infinity. Things may very well be reversed for small `n`.

Comment: @mitchus,In fact actual usability is that what interesting me more . What do you consider as small n ?

Comment: Well, it really depends on the algorithms. For instance, imagine an algorithm that performs `3 n^2` multiplications, which is `O(n^2)`, and another algorithm that makes `1,000,000 n` calls to a very expensive function, i.e. `O(n)`. Even though asymptotically the second is best, if for your problem you have `n` around 100 the first is much better. Essentially, if usability is what you are after I would advise you to look at comparative studies of performance rather than theoretical complexity, or even better, if multiple algorithms are available, try them all and compare :)

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Comment: @mitchus,Thanks for very detailed and useful comment...

Comment: @Raphael,Should I post the same question over there or to try migrate this one ?

Comment: The site is not yet live. You can commit to the proposal, though, to *make* it come live.

Answer (score 1):

First, for any given fixed `n`, just put it in the runtime function (sans the Landau O, mind you) and compare.

Asymptotically, you can divide one function (resp its Landau term) by the other and consider the quotient's limit for `n` to infinity. If it is zero, the function in the nominator grows properly, asymptotically weaker than the other. If it is infinity, it grows properly faster. In all other cases, the have the same asymptotic grows up to a constant factor (i.e. big Theta). If the quotient is `1` in the limit, they are asymptotically equal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, according to [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division) about application of Newton method to division , you have to do `O(lg(n))` steps to calculate `n` bits of division. Every step employs multiplication and subtraction, so has bit complexity `O(n^2)` in case we employ simple "schoolbook" method.

So, complexity of first approach is `O(lg(n) * n^2)`. It's asymptotically [slower](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28lg%28n%29%20%2a%20n%5E2%29/%28lg%28n%29%5E6%29%20as%20n-%3Einfinity) than second approach.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying that O(k*M(n)) is more "expensive" than O(log^6(n)) ?

Comment: ,What if we choose some other method instead of "schoolbook" method ?

Comment: Then you would have result complexity `O(lg(n) * X)`, where `X` is complexity of that method (from your Wikipedia link). But, as far as I know, all other multiplication methods are rather complex to implement in practice.

Comment: So I can conclude that first approach is of polynomial complexity ?

Comment: No, it's not of polynomial complexity, because of `lg(n)` multiplier. I don't know term for this kind of complexity. Next "less efficient" complexity,  after polynomial, according to Wikipedia is "sub-exponential".

Comment: @VictorSorocin,As far as I know `O(n^3)` is known as polynomial complexity, and `O(log(n)*n^2)`  is asymptotically faster...

Comment: Actually, it depends on what $n$ is. If $n$ is the size of the inputs (in bits), then what you have here is polynomial. If it is a number that constitutes the input, you have a pseudo-polynomial algorithm.

Comment: Note also that asymptotics do *not* directly give you which algorithm is more or less expensive. The latter also depends on which input sizes you consider; for small input sizes, an asymptotically slower algorithm may be preferred; consider for instance `1000*n` vs `1.00001^n`. In practice, space complexity is also an issue, among many more.